# Rails ActiveRecord Joining Queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently use two queries to solve my problem and I'm sure it's possible to merge them into one. I currently have:

```
guest = Guest.find_by(email: params[:email].downcase)
booking = Booking.find_by(guest_id: guest.id)
```

The Guest and Booking models are related - One Guest has many Bookings.

I think I saw on the Rails guides somewhere how to do this with just one query but I cannot find the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have your model associations in place, the answer is far simpler than you think:

```
bookings = Guest.find_by_email(params[:email].downcase).bookings
```

No need for joins in this case.

Comment: yes thanks! that's what I saw - because of the associations it's dead simple but just can't remember where I saw it ha ha

Comment: yeah just realised that - will alter - no probs

Comment: @depa Using your syntax is becoming deprecated. It's still somehow ok in Rails 4.0 but will be totally removed in Rails 4.1, so I wouldn't point him (and others) in that direction, bro. Perhaps you'd want to edit to find_by( email: ... ) syntax rather than the old find_by_email syntax. It's ok to edit an answer.

Comment: good suggestion - I actually used find_by and not find_by_email myself having noticed the deprecation warning in my terminal a few days back. Good spot

Comment: However, just playing around with it now and I'm getting "undefined method `bookings' for nil:NilClass" - my associations are def setup

Comment: That probably means you don't have a guest with the email you searched for.

Comment: @tommyd456 Then try Guest.find_by_email(params[:email].downcase).try :bookings . But you'll still have to deal with possibly no guest by that email.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways. The main object is not to write less lines, but to have readable code.

I'd do it this way bro:

```
# For style and readability, put this in a separate line:
email = params[:email].downcase
# then:
bookings = Guest.find_by( email: email ).bookings
```

Make sure you've declared that the `Guest` class `has_many :bookings`.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but i think that this idiom would result in two different queries instead of a single query.

Comment: @lefty you're right. Changed to `Guest.find_by( email: email ).bookings`

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken you could try

```
Booking.joins(:guest).where(guests: {email: params[:email].downcase}).all
```

Check out also http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html for more info.

Comment: I suspect he want to retrieve a Booking rather than a Guest, in which case the correct instruction would be : `Booking.joins( :guest ).where( guest: { email: params[:email].downcase }).first` (if booking belongs to guest)

Comment: Yes it's a booking I require but the controller is only provided with a guest's email to retrieve the booking - thanks for the suggestions guys